# Office365 Users SSO for Atlassian and Slack

Tags: microsoft-office, user-accounts, single-sign-on

So we're currently using Office365 and we have just started to use the Atlassian product range and Slack. I want to try and have a central place for all my users and add / remove staff as when required.

Is it possible to do this through Office365 or would I need to use something else? My main goal is to allow all users to use SSO into everything and then administer them from a central place.

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

I've recently come across crowd:
https://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd

It doesn't come with office365 integration out of the box but I'm sure it could be linked up with a bit of customisation, possibly through openID.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin does **exactly** what you are looking for on the Atlassian product range: https://www.cleito.com/products/odcc/

(Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of this plugin)

Comment: It would be clearer that it does exactly what the OP wants if you describe what it does and doesn't do, and maybe add a little flavor of how it works.  Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Otherwise, the answer may be perceived as a little bit spammy.  Thanks.

Comment: The ODCC plugin allows you to manage your Atlassian users and groups in a central place which is Office 365 administration portal. With the ODCC plugin, an Office 365 account also becomes an Atlassian stack (e.g Jira, Confluence) account and users enter their Office 365 credentials to log into Atlassian server products. Once logged into an application using Crowd (+ODCC) as its user management system, users do not have to authenticate again thanks to Crowd SSO.